# Composer dando erro

Tags: php, composer

Tentei instalar o `phpunit` pelo `composer` no Windows 7, porém não está permitindo.
Nem o `phpunit` e nenhum outra ferramenta/pacote/framework.

O erro que está exibindo é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e meu arquivo de `json` é esse:

```
{
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "*"
},
"autoload" :{
    "psr-0":{
        "Example":"lib"
    }
}
```

}

comando para "rodar" o `composer`

```
composer install
```

Abaixo estão os detalhes do `composer`

`composer` diagnose
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você verificou essa questão de certificados?

Answer (score 0):

É necessário você configurar o módulo `openssl` do PHP.

Primeiro baixe o certificado na sua máquina:

```
curl -o ca-bundle.crt http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

Depois configure o caminho dos certificados no `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo=/caminho/para/certificados/ca-bundle.crt
openssl.cafile=/caminho/para/certificados/ca-bundle.crt
```

Então tente fazer o download novamente.

Comment: precisa ser uma pasta especifica para o certificado ou qualquer uma que eu decidir?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer uma, desde que o PHP tenha permissões de leitura a essa pasta. Por via das dúvidas, coloque na própria pasta do PHP.

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso.

Comment: curl.cainfo e opessl.cafile estão no arquivo php.ini ? pq aqui não encontrei esses. PS. to usando o xamp no windows